# Latin-1 to UTF-8 conversion with mixed content

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

Originally, we ran a database with `UTF-8` encoding and we had to migrate to a different server which was using `latin-1` by mistake. The problem is that most names contain special foreign characters and they get rendered weird without the proper encoding:

For example:

Nezihe ÅžÃ¼kran AkkaÅŸ
LÃœTFÄ° Ã‡OBAN
Eren KaragÃ¶zlÃ¼

I was able to convert it back to UTF using the following query:
`SELECT convert(cast(convert(name using  latin1) as binary) using UTF8) AS name FROM users;`

The above names now appeared correctly:

Nezihe Şükran Akkaş
LÜTFİ ÇOBAN
Eren Karagözlü

However, all the data that was previously encoded as proper UTF-8 now appears as `(NULL)`

My question is how do I convert only the broken encoding rows and leave the properly encoded one's untouched? Right now, it's "either or". The problem is they are mixed in terms of order so I can't separate them by ID.

Any clue would help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: i noticed this some weeks ago, but didn't report it

Comment: Fixes _depend on the situation_:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases  More discussion:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just `select coalesce( convert(...), name )`?